# What is more efficient, creating a new string and saving a substring to it, then concat new string together or performing multiple substring concats?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn what is more efficient. I would like to return a subsection of string and wish to know what works best.

`return str.Substring(0, 3) + str.Substring(0, 3) + str.Substring(0, 3);`

or

```
string newStr = str.Substring(0, 3);

return newStr + newStr + newStr;
```

Both ways pass the unit tests so just looking for efficiency ideas.

Comment: "and trying to learn what is more efficient" --- given you're learning the most important lesson is: there are no universal micro-optimisation recipes, you must micro-benchmark every case (and also check the final IL).

Comment: Make a `for` loop and run both implementations of the same function a million times and measure the time. Anyway I guess the second option should be faster because there's only 1 function call instead of 3.

Comment: `string.Format(“{0}{0}{0}”, str.Substring(0, 3)` of course.

Comment: @JohnWu I like the string.Format way but how is that better than what I've already tried?

Comment: @JohnWu, I thought so too, but when I ran it over a million times in a loop, string.Format is significantly slower than both the other options here.

Comment: Take a look at the `StringBuilder` for a different approach on concatenating strings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: [StringBuilder.AppendFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat). If you're looking for *performace*, don't concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET offers a really handy way to benchmark your code, stopwatches! You can read about how to use them here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8

You should try using a stopwatch for both of those methods you have described and see which one is faster, or if you are more worried about memory usage you could use visual studio's inbuilt debugging tools.

Once you know how to use these tools you can find the answers yourself and draw your own conclusions, but don't forget to also consider code readability :) Good luck!

Comment: Thank you I will look over the suggested document. I do need to learn how to use tools better.

Comment: @DavidKoch Have fun and good luck! The .NET documentation is useful and contains many good answers. If you feel my answer satisfied your question you may accept it. Here is some more info on accepting answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer